# Calculate distance matrix for list of coordinates in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a list of coordinates:

```py
l_coords = [(1, 2), (1.1, 2.2), (1.05, 1.9)]
```

how can I calculate the distance matrix using a vectorized experession in numpy?

Comment: Can you clarify the logic and provide the expected output (with a breakdown of the computation)

Comment: If you want a pairwise distance: `from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform ; squareform(pdist(l_coords))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, or `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

l_coords = [(1, 2), (1.1, 2.2), (1.05, 1.9)]
cdist(l_coords, l_coords)
>>> array([[0.        , 0.2236068 , 0.1118034 ],
           [0.2236068 , 0.        , 0.30413813],
           [0.1118034 , 0.30413813, 0.        ]])
```

Comment: If this is what OP wants, `squareform(pdist(l_coords))`